# Format message in custom JSF validator

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

I am implementing a custom validator. The detail for messages in stored in the resources. Here is an example of a message: `Value is required for {0}`. {0} should contain the label of the component.

```
@FacesValidator("customValidator")
public class CustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (validatorCondition()) {
            String summary = Res.getString("error");
            String detail =  ... format detail here
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, summary, detail));
        } 
    }
}
```

How can I format the messaged displayed in the validate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MessageFormat#format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

```
String template = "Value is required for {0}.";
String label = component.getAttributes().get("label"); // Don't forget to handle nulls. JSF defaults to client ID.
String message = MessageFormat.format(template, label);
// ...
```